# Is Spring's QueryByExampleExecutor usable with Projections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is there a way to return Iterable< IUser > where IUser is a projection of User entity.

```
Example<User> userExample = Example.of(user, userMatcher);
Iterable<User> foundUsers = userRepository.findAll(userExample, Sort.by("createdAt").descending());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of sticking with spring data auto generated query and response type.

You can create your own HQL query by using `@Query` annotation so that you can except your custom return type.

Example :

```
@Query(" select user from User as user where user.userName like %:username% order by createdAt desc")
public List<User> findAllByUserName(String username);
```